# error message in form not displaying correctly rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating a blog application in rails.

Ruby version -> 2.5.1
Rails version -> 5.1.7

I have a user model in which I am validating the password and it's confirmation must match.

```
validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6, maximum: 20}

validates :password,  confirmation: {case_sensitive: true , message: "Passwords don't match"}
```

Now, when I am submitting the form with different password and it's confirmation, the error message showing at the top is:

```
2 errors found.
Password confirmation Passwords don't match
Password confirmation doesn't match Password
```

And what I was expecting:

```
1 error found.
Passwords don't match
```

This is the code of the form view, if required:

```
#The errors partial is just iterating over the user object errors and displaying them.
<%= render 'shared/errors', obj: @user %>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
    <%= f.label :password %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter password" %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="control-label col-sm-2">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password' %>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Enter password again" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :articles
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: {case_sensitive: false},
    length: {minimum: 3, maximum: 25}

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i

  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 105 },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }

  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6, maximum: 20}

  validate :password_check

  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }

  has_secure_password

  private
  def password_check
    # Check for nils and blanks
    errors.add(:base, "Passwords don't match") if password != password_confirmation
  end

end
```

[image: error message screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message of activerecord and the custom error message you added are printed at the same time. When you remove the custom error message from the validation, I think problem will solve.

If you want to add a custom error message, change [default activerecord error message](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml) as follows:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              confirmation: "don't match"
```

**UPDATE**

If the above method does not solve the problem, you can write custom validation:

Remove `validates :password,  confirmation: ..`

```
validate :confirm_password

private
def confirm_password
  return if password == password_confirmation
  errors.add(:password, "don't match")
end
```

Comment: not getting the custom error message. Getting the active record error message : "Password confirmation doesn't match Password" which I don't want.

Comment: Now the message I am getting is: 
2 errors found.
Password don't match
Password confirmation doesn't match Password

The custom error is right. But getting again the active record message.

Comment: @Bhawan Remove validates :password,  confirmation: .. line

Comment: Removed already. 
Now it looks like:
  validates :password, presence: true, length: {minimum: 6, maximum: 20}

  validate :password_check

Comment: @denir, i had to rename the password_confirmation to password_check otherwise it was throwing error 'Stack level too deep'. It is because function name and field name are same in that case.

Comment: Hmm ok. So I updated the answer. The new method name is confirm_password @Bhawan

Comment: This generates 'Password don't match' (singular and grammatically incorrect), that's why I'm suggesting `:base` in my answer.

Comment: Still I am getting the active record error message and custom message both. The custom error is correct this time.

Comment: @Bhawan Are you using Devise?

Comment: @Bhawan Can you share the user model?

Comment: @Bhawan remove has_secure_password

Comment: After removing has_secure_password, the error I am getting now is: unknown attribute 'password' for User.

Comment: @Bhawan try has_secure_password :password, validations: false

Comment: Error: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Comment: @Bhawan try has_secure_password validations: false

Answer (score 0):

The configuration options are unnecesary since `sensitive_case: true` is the default, and `message` if causing the double error message.

`validates :password,  confirmation: true` will give you

```
1 error found.
Password confirmation doesn't match Password
```

If you really need that custom message you should write your own validate method and add the error to `base`:

```rb
# validates :password,  confirmation: {case_sensitive: true , message: "Passwords don't match"}
validate :password_check

private
def password_check
  # Check for nils and blanks
  errors.add(:base, "Passwords don't match") if password != password_confirmation
end
```

Comment: Sorry. Remove `end` after `errors.add`. Answer edited.

Comment: errors.add(:base, 'Passwords don't match') if password <> password_confirmation
The single quotes in don't is creating the problem.

Comment: I'm sorry again. Edited.

Comment: Getting both custom and active record error message. And <> operator is also giving error so changed to !=

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm mixing languages, my bad. Did you comment out the line `validates :password, confirmation:...`?

Comment: Yes , I have updated the user model in the question.

Comment: `has_secure_password` is running that validation for you, so you are safe removing it. Is it really that important the custom message?

Comment: After removing it, getting other errors related to password and password_confirmation fields.

Comment: My suggestion is to leave `has_secure_password` alone, and remove the validation for password confirmation.

Comment: Doing this is allowing me to create users even with a mismatched password and password_confirmation fields.

Comment: I don't think `has_secure_password` allows you to do that: https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password

Comment: For further customizability, it is possible to suppress the default validations by passing validations: false as an argument.